# Pack UV islands with their same scale?

Tags: uv

Is there a way or add-on that allow for UV packing without re-scaling the islands? like 'Pack together' in 3ds Max.

[image]

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried *UV/Image Editor > UVs > Average Islands Scale*?

Comment: @brockmann Sorry if my question is not clear, what I want is packing the islands without scaling it to fit the whole UV boundary.

Comment: "Pack together" sounds to me like doing uniform scale and packing at once. If that's right, it's just a combination of `Ctrl A` and `Ctrl P`. If I'm wrong, please try to add more detail to find a solution, I don't have access to max right now @user48739

Comment: Okay I edited the post, hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for some time I found that there is no such function in blender, so I tried to make an add-on that provide this function.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwE1PQiqCb0

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Kindly share the addon link here as well